# wordpress got hacked with htaccess and some python and perl code

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My WordPress website has been hacked.
There has been no change in the appearance of the website yet, but for example the .htaccess file is filled with strange code, and when I edit the file with valid information, the file suddenly returns to its previous state. The same thing happens with index.php file.
this is the content of htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch '.(php|php5|phtml)$'>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch '^(index.php|auto_seo.php|wp-blog-header.php|wp-config-sample.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-login.php|wp-settings.php|wp-trackback.php|wp-activate.php|wp-comments-post.php|wp-cron.php|wp-load.php|wp-mail.php|wp-signup.php|xmlrpc.php|edit-form-advanced.php|link-parse-opml.php|ms-sites.php|options-writing.php|themes.php|admin-ajax.php|edit-form-comment.php|link.php|ms-themes.php|plugin-editor.php|admin-footer.php|edit-link-form.php|load-scripts.php|ms-upgrade-network.php|admin-functions.php|edit.php|load-styles.php|ms-users.php|plugins.php|admin-header.php|edit-tag-form.php|media-new.php|my-sites.php|post-new.php|admin.php|edit-tags.php|media.php|nav-menus.php|post.php|admin-post.php|export.php|media-upload.php|network.php|press-this.php|upload.php|async-upload.php|menu-header.php|options-discussion.php|privacy.php|user-edit.php|menu.php|options-general.php|profile.php|user-new.php|moderation.php|options-head.php|revision.php|users.php|custom-background.php|ms-admin.php|options-media.php|setup-config.php|widgets.php|custom-header.php|ms-delete-site.php|options-permalink.php|term.php|customize.php|link-add.php|ms-edit.php|options.php|edit-comments.php|link-manager.php|ms-options.php|options-reading.php|system_log.php)$'>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Remove the `filesMatch` blocks those are useless and not being used at all by your server.

Comment: when I try to remove something the file will update to the above content again.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that update the htaccess automatically?

Comment: @AmitVerma no I don`t, actually file update automatically before any refresh or anything else, at exactly moment that I save the file it will change.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why it is a deadly security fault to insist on being able to write the sites configuration files by the wordpress software. Configurations should _never_ be writeable by the software controlled by that configuration.

Comment: A general rule of thumb: if you don't understand what is going on in your own web site then you should take it offline _now_ .

Comment: @arkascha actually I did it, the site is offline now, and I`m trying to find out how to solve this problem